# I started new application in my Android Studio, while syncing the files got error on Gradle syncing file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> Error: Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\user1\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.sonatype.oss\oss-parent\9' when creating directory 'C:\Users\user1\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.sonatype.oss\oss-parent\9\e5cdc4d23b86d79c436f16fed20853284e868f65'

When i am installing android studio i received an error "Error opening file for writing " relates to apache-9.pom file. I neglected and ignore that error now it is showing error project is not syncing and editing and debugging is not working.

Comment: You could try to delete the `C:\Users\user1.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.sonatype.oss` folder

Comment: Check your Android studio Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Build Tools/Gradle for the `Service directory path`. It should be `C:/Users/user1/.gradle` and I guess you are missing the final slash

Comment: \ is there in my path. while posting here it is not showing, it is missing. In my Android studio Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Build Tools/Gradle for the Service directory path is also same as you mentioned. @devnull69

Comment: I deleted the folder as you referred but the error remains same. @cricket_007

Comment: Are you trying to use Maven as the repository instead of Jcenter?

Comment: uninstalled android studio and cleared all files. again installed while installing received an error "Error opening file for writing " relates to gradle folder apache-9.pom file and it shows options ABORT setup and IGNORE.   i ignored.

Comment: No @cricket_007 .. I didnt change anything. it is using jcenter() only.

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle` files, please?

Comment: From app folder build.gradle:  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.user.googlemaps"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
 }
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: sorry guys. lost some registry files in my PC.So the issue facing on some other applications also, i did format. Now everything working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean project
2. Rebuild project
3. Sync Gradle
   if doesn't work try to check build tool

or - clean out the system caches:

On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart. The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart IntelliJ IDEA or both.

**Gradle cache**

Gradle cache locates at

On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.gradle/caches/ You can browse to these directory and manually delete it or run

Comment: first i preferred Invalidate and restart but the error continues and next CLEAN PROJECT  then it shows Gradle build message........Information:Gradle tasks [clean]
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/oss-parent-9.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom.       downloaded these POM files but where we have to store.

Comment: sorry guys. lost some registry files in my PC.So the issue facing on some other applications also, i did format. Now everything working fine. :)